# Master Detail app in Swift - how to convert string into URL

Tags: swift, url

I'm new here, so please bear with me.  I have a Master-Detail app, and in the DetailViewController.swift file, here's the configureView func where it calls a web view to open a web page.

It's complaining on the let request = URLRequest(url:url) line because url variable is defined as a string.  I've tried everything but it won't work.

By the way, `MasterViewController.MyVariables.urlString` is an array of strings.

```
func configureView() {
    // Update the user interface for the detail item.
    if let detail: AnyObject = detailItem {
        if let myWebview = webView {
            let url =   MasterViewController.MyVariables.urlString
            let request = URLRequest(url: url)
            myWebview.scalesPageToFit = true
            myWebview.loadRequest(request)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just pass a new URL `URL(string: url)`

Comment: Cannot convert value of type '[String]?' to expected argument type 'URL'

Comment: let request = URL(String: url) giving me error Argument labels '(String:)' do not match any available overloads

Comment: string not String `let request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: MasterViewController.MyVariables.urlString)!)`

Comment: Hi there, thanks for the comment, but it's still giving me an error.

Comment: Cannot convert value of type '[String]?' to expected argument type 'String'

Comment: update your question with your actual code. Don't forget to post MasterViewController declaration

Comment: probably you need to pass `MasterViewController.MyVariables.urlString?.first ?? ""`

Comment: I can only guess if you don't post your whole code related to the question

Comment: It's pretty confusing to name an array in a singular form. It's supposed to be `urlStrings`. And why is the array declared as optional which obviously contains a value?

Answer (score 1):

You can either pass an `URL` object or create an `URL` object from the string that you´re passing. Anyhow you need to convert your string into an `URL`.

```
if let url = URL(string: MasterViewController.MyVariables.urlString) {
    // use url in here
}
```

**Update:**
Use this for your example:

```
if let url = URL(string: MasterViewController.MyVariables.urlString) {
    // use url in here
    let request = URLRequest(url: url)
}
```

**Update 2:**
You have your `Struct` which is an `array of strings`. Then you need to do this to get the value you want:

```
struct MyVariables {
    static var urlString: [String]? = ["something"]
}

if let str = MyVariables.urlString?.first, let url = URL(string: str) {
    // use url in here
    let request = URLRequest(url: url)
    print(url)
}
```

Right now I´m using `MyVariables.urlString?.first`, in the future if you want another index then you need to get that instead.

Comment: You forgot to unwrap the url

Comment: if let url = URL(string: MasterViewController.MyVariables.urlString) {
                    // use url in here
                    let request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: MasterViewController.MyVariables.urlString)!)
                }

Comment: Cannot convert value of type '[String]?' to expected argument type 'String'

Comment: `URLRequest(url: url)`

Comment: You´re using it wrong. Check the update and read the lines to understand how to use it. You´re declaring an `if let url` to use it.

Comment: MasterViewController.MyVariables.urlString it is definitely not a String. You can tell it by looking at the error OP is getting

Comment: func configureView() {
        // Update the user interface for the detail item.
        
        if let detail: AnyObject = detailItem {
            
            if let myWebview = webView {
                
                if let url = URL(string: MasterViewController.MyVariables.urlString) {
                    // use url in here
                    let request = URLRequest(url: url)
                }
                
                myWebview.scalesPageToFit = true
                myWebview.loadRequest(request)
            }
        }
    }

Comment: Sorry, you are right.  MasterViewController.MyVariables.urlString is an array of string.

Comment: struct MyVariables {
        static var urlString: [String]? = ["something"]
    }

Comment: @ms_abc, check the update 2. You need to understand the fundamentals before you do these stuffs. Read the documentation and tryout what the difference between a string and an array of strings are. Then you also need to understand what the URL does and how you can use it. Hopefully you get it now with the latest update, good luck!

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did to make it work:

let stringRepresentation = MasterViewController.MyVariables.urlString?.joined(separator:"")

```
            print ("urlString", MasterViewController.MyVariables.urlString)
            print ("sR",stringRepresentation)

            let url = NSURL(string: stringRepresentation as! String)
            let request = URLRequest(url: url! as URL)

            myWebview.scalesPageToFit = true
            myWebview.loadRequest(request)
```